# How to use the user profile photo as the default image in a content type image field?

Tags: 8, nodes, users

I would like to pull the current user profile photo in a content type image field but the default image option only allows the admin to choose an image file. Is there a module that allows the admin to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any module that does this.

Setting the user profile image as the default value for a content type image will result in data duplication because the image file will be copied for each instance.

To eliminate this duplication, you could use media images and set the user profile image as a reference to a media image (which would require some rewriting of the logic for handling user profile images), and then use a media image entity reference field on the content type instead of an image field.  This could be a useful contrib module but it does not exist.